# How to compare object with array #ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have array in Json parson like this :

```
{"id" => "cat", "name" => "Kitty"}, {"id" => "dog", "name" => "Pop"}
```

I want compare with object name I input

```
@pet =ARGV[0]
my_list.each do |list|
      if list[name] == @pet
            puts " The ID of pet: #{"id"} "
      end
end
```

It's not working, how to do this ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? input(s) and expected output?

Comment: Ex: I input @pet = Pop in terminal : ruby example.rb "Pop" ---> expect output: "The ID of pet: dog"

Comment: "It's not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

For example, `my_list` equals:

```
my_list = [{"id" => "cat", "name" => "Kitty"}, {"id" => "dog", "name" => "Pop"}]
```

Then you can find the associated value using [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
@pet = ARGV[0]
my_list = [{"id" => "cat", "name" => "Kitty"}, {"id" => "dog", "name" => "Pop"}]   
pet_object = my_list.find { |object| object["name"] == @pet }
puts " The ID of pet: #{pet_object["id"]} " if pet_object
```

Or you can modify your code, which will also work:

```
@pet = ARGV[0]
my_list = [{"id" => "cat", "name" => "Kitty"}, {"id" => "dog", "name" => "Pop"}]
my_list.each do |list|
  if list["name"] == @pet
    puts " The ID of pet: #{list["id"]} "
  end
end
```

Comment: Another point, which way you gave is better to do? I means faster

Comment: @XCage they will have almost the same time of execution. the only difference is that the iteration in the first way will stop, when it finds a value, but in the second one the list will always be iterated to the end